# NavigationBar component with hooks. Can it be made more readable/maintainable?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, react.js

I wrote a NavigationBar component in React, using hooks, react-bootstrap, react-i18next and css. Now the component works as I expect it, but the code seems ugly. (I'm new with hooks)

Features:

- It's transparent at the beginning but if we scroll down it will be "dark" (from react-bootstrap)
- If there's no enough space to show everything (768px) then the menu collapses and a hamburger menu will be shown
- If the hamburger menu opens then the background will be always "dark". It goes back to transparent if it closes and it should be transparent.

Can be this component refactored, so it's easier to read/understand to a new developer? (Or maintain it for that matter)

How?

Also, I'm a bit baffled about the component tests. To check if the background of the navigation bar changes properly as I scroll down and up I would need an environment where I can scroll (an actual browser?) which seems quite complicated with react testing library and jest. Any suggestion here? Maybe I should mock the window values somehow? Or just test the functions and not doing any scrolling?

Thank you!

*Note:* LanguageSelector component is a NavDropdown with 2 elements to change the language accordingly. When user clicks on one of the items "changeLanguage(language:string): void" function is called from NavigationBar component (it is passed via props as you can see in the code)

You can try the component here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-blackburn-htxc5

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import LangaugeSelector from '../LanguageSelector/LanguageSelector';
import './NavigationBar.css';

function NavigationBar() {
    const startingNavbarColor = 'transparent';
    const navbarColor = 'dark';
    const compactLayoutWidth = 768;

    // State: NavBackground, Event: Scroll
    const [navBackground, setNavBackground] = useState(false);
    const navRef: React.MutableRefObject<boolean> = useRef(false);
    navRef.current = navBackground;
    const handleScroll = useCallback(event => {
        if (!navRef.current && window.scrollY > 200) {
            setNavBackground(true);
        }
        else if (navRef.current && window.scrollY <= 200) {
            setNavBackground(false);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle((event) => handleScroll(event), 100));
        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }, [handleScroll]);

    // State: CompactLayout, Event: Resize
    const [compactLayout, setCompactLayout] = useState(window.innerWidth <= compactLayoutWidth);
    const layoutRef: React.MutableRefObject<boolean> = useRef(false);
    layoutRef.current = compactLayout;
    const handleResize = useCallback(event => {
        if (window.innerWidth > compactLayoutWidth && layoutRef.current) {
            setCompactLayout(false);
            setNavbarExpanded(false);
        }
        else if (window.innerWidth <= compactLayoutWidth && !layoutRef.current) {
            setCompactLayout(true);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', throttle((event) => handleResize(event), 100));
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, [handleResize]);

    // State: NavbarExpanded, Event: OnToggle
    const [navbarExpanded, setNavbarExpanded] = useState(false);
    const navbarExpandedRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
    navbarExpandedRef.current = navbarExpanded;
    const handleExpand = (expanded: boolean) => {
        if (expanded && !navbarExpandedRef.current) {
            setNavbarExpanded(true);
        } else if (!expanded && navbarExpandedRef.current) {
            setNavbarExpanded(false);
        }
    };

    // Calculating the navbar background
    const getNavbarBackground = () => {
        if (!navbarExpandedRef.current && !navRef.current) {
            return startingNavbarColor;
        } else {
            return navbarColor;
        }
    }

    // Language
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    const changeLanguage = (language: string) => {
        i18n.changeLanguage(language);
        handleExpand(false);
    }

    // Render
    return (
        <Navbar fixed="top" bg={getNavbarBackground()} variant="dark" 
                onToggle={handleExpand} expand="md"     // if you change 'expand' value, don't forget to change 'compactLayoutWidth' accordingly as well
                expanded={navbarExpandedRef.current} collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home"> {t('name')} </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse>
                <Nav id="collapseableNav">
                    <Nav.Link href="#aboutme">{t('aboutMe')}</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#contact">{t('contact')}</Nav.Link>
                    {
                        compactLayout &&
                        <LangaugeSelector languages={['en', 'hu']} changeLanguage={changeLanguage} alignRight={false} /> 
                    }
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>

            {
                !compactLayout &&
                <Nav id="separateLanguageNav" className="justify-content-end">
                    <LangaugeSelector languages={['en', 'hu']} changeLanguage={changeLanguage} alignRight={true} /> 
                </Nav>
            }
        </Navbar>
    );
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Comment: This question, `Can be this component refactored, so it's easier to read/understand to a new developer? (Or maintain it for that matter)` will only lead to a yes/no answer.

Comment: Added the "How?" question, but I thought it's obvious that I expect more than a Yes/No. Otherwise it is not too useful, is it? :) (Also added a link to codesandbox where the component can be tried out)